# What are bus reliability method?

Tags: communication, digital-communications, bus

Busses provides to IC the ability to communicate to each other. But this communication can be blurred due to noise coming from or outside the circuit. I know there is ways to lower the impact of perturbation:

- Differential bus line. The information is bring from one IC to another thanks to two twisted wires. Since these two wire are very close to each other, they will both be impact by the noise. The receiver compute the difference between the two voltage to get the real value. The CAN bus use this technique :

[image]

- Some protocol can trigger error in the bus and some times even "repair" it.

Is there other methods to improve the quality of communication use by busses?

Comment: You mean like, shielding, or using fibre-optics, current loops?

Comment: @WesleyLee Any software or hardware methods that can improve the quality if the communication. So yes, I guess that shielding is a good exemple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking to brief you on an entire very sizable branch of electrical engineering and computer science. Not being an expert in the field, these are the major methods in improving channel reliability, in brief, starting from physical layer to logical layers:

1. [low-voltage] differential signaling is a must;
2. Use pre-emphasis(de-emphasis) to compensate channel losses at transmitter side, and adaptive linear equalization on receiver side. Use "link training" periodically to optimize channel in case of channel changing properties;
3. Use balanced signal encoding, when positive and negative transitions/bits are equally distributed over time (NRZI as an example);
4. Use symbol-encoding with redundancy, 8b/10b, 128b/132b, instead of simple bit-wise data representation;
5. Use packet formats with real-time CRC (circular redundancy check) and other redundancy methods, some of which allows automatic recovery up to certain number of faulty bits;
6. Use hardware-based re-try mechanism in case of CRC/packet recovery failure;
7. Use triple-redundant channels with majority logic correction/recovery.
8. anything else? Please add ...

I'd vote to close the question as "too broad".

Comment: Yes, I know that question is very (very very) board... Thanks a lot, I'll look to all the point you highlight on this post. I'll add some if I find some more

Answer (score 0):

For electric-field aggressors, reduce the differential-bus impedance; that is, don't run at 100 ohms differential if you have a 50 ohm or 25 ohm choice. And reducing the aggressor slewrate (edge rate) and transition-density helps, because with fewer upsets the Error-Detect-Correct codes have a chance to be useful.

Ensure you twisted-pairs are machine-wound, not human-wound. A uniform twist is key to rejecting Efields, because uniform twists are more likely to experience uniform charge injections (additive noise).

For magnetic-field aggressors, reduce the loop area (lower Zo twisted pairs are closer together) and implement a closed-path solid-conductor shield to use field cancellation. That is, ground the shield (at least for high frequencies, using 1nF or 100nF caps) at both ends.